# Play framework akka stream websocket handling message get sent to deadletters

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm trying to wrap my head around akka streams and the way to handle web sockets, but some things are quite clear to me. 
For starters, I'm trying to accomplish one-way communication from some client to the server and communication between the same server and some other client.

```
client1 -----> Server <------> client2
```

I was looking at the example provided [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-websocket-example/tree/2.6.x/app/actors). 
The resulting code looks something like this:

1) starting with the controller

```
class Test @Inject()(@Named("connManager") myConnectionsManager: ActorRef, cc: ControllerComponents)
                (implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                 val mat: Materializer,
                 implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
extends AbstractController(cc) {


private def wsFutureFlow(id: String): Future[Flow[String, String, NotUsed]] = {
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
    val future = myConnectionsManager ? CreateRemote(id)
    val futureFlow = future.mapTo[Flow[String, String, NotUsed]]
    futureFlow
}

private def wsFutureLocalFlow: Future[Flow[String, String, NotUsed]] =   {
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
    val future = myConnectionsManager ? CreateLocal
    val futureFlow = future.mapTo[Flow[String, String, NotUsed]]
    futureFlow
}

def ws: WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] {

    rh =>
        wsFutureFlow(rh.id.toString).map { flow =>
            Right(flow)
        }
}

def wsLocal: WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] {

    _ =>
        wsFutureLocalFlow.map { flow =>
            Right(flow)
        }
}
}
```

As for the connection manager actor. That would be the equivalent of the UserParentActor from the example.

```
class MyConnectionsManager @Inject()(childFactory: MyTestActor.Factory)
                                (implicit ec: ExecutionContext, mat: Materializer) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {

import akka.pattern.{ask, pipe}

implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(2.seconds)

override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateRemote(x) =>
        val child = injectedChild(childFactory(), s"remote-$x")
        context.watch(child)
        privatePipe(child)
    case CreateLocal =>
        val child = injectedChild(childFactory(), "localConnection")
        context.become(onLocalConnected(child))
        privatePipe(child)
    case Terminated(child) =>
        println(s"${child.path.name} terminated...")
}

def onLocalConnected(local: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case CreateRemote(x) =>
        val child = injectedChild(childFactory(), s"remote-$x")
        context.watch(child)
        privatePipe(child)
    case x: SendToLocal => local ! x
}

private def privatePipe(child: ActorRef) = {
    val future = (child ? Init).mapTo[Flow[String, String, _]]
    pipe(future) to sender()
    () // compiler throws exception without this: non-unit value discarded
    }
}
```

And the MyTestActor looks like this:

```
class MyTestActor @Inject()(implicit mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor {

val source: Source[String, Sink[String, NotUsed]] = MergeHub.source[String]
  .recoverWithRetries(-1, { case _: Exception => Source.empty })

private val jsonSink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach { json =>
    println(s"${self.path.name} got message:  $json")

    context.parent ! SendToLocal(json)
}

private lazy val websocketFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = {
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(jsonSink, source).watchTermination() { (_, termination) =>
        val name = self.path.name
        termination.foreach(_ => context.stop(self))
        NotUsed
    }
}

def receive: Receive = {

    case Init =>
        println(s"${self.path.name}: INIT")
        sender ! websocketFlow
    case SendToLocal(x) =>
        println(s"Local got from remote: $x")
    case msg: String => sender ! s"Actor got message: $msg"
    }
}
```

What I don't understand, apart from how sinks and sources actually connect to the actors, is the following. When I start up my system, I send a few messages to the actor. However, after I close the connection to an actor named remote, and continue sending messages to the one called "localConnection", the messages get sent to DeadLetters:

```
[info] Done compiling.
[info] 15:49:20.606 - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
localConnection: INIT
localConnection got message:  test data
Local got from remote: test data
localConnection got message:  hello world
Local got from remote: hello world
remote-133: INIT
remote-133 got message:  hello world
Local got from remote: hello world
remote-133 got message:  hello from remote
Local got from remote: hello from remote
[error] 15:50:24.449 - a.a.OneForOneStrategy - Monitored actor [Actor[akka://application/user/connManager/remote-133#-998945083]] terminated
akka.actor.DeathPactException: Monitored actor [Actor[akka://application/user/connManager/remote-133#-998945083]] terminated
deadLetters got message:  hello local
```

I assume this is because of the exception thrown... Can anyone explain to me as to why the message gets sent to DeadLetters?
Apart from that, I would like to know why I keep getting a compiler exception without the "()" returned at the end of `privatePipe`?

Also, should I be doing anything differently?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the exception was being thrown because I forgot to handle the Terminated message in the new behaviour of the MyConnectionsManager actor.

```
def onLocalConnected(local: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case CreateRemote(x) =>
        val child = injectedChild(childFactory(), s"remote-$x")
        context.watch(child)
        privatePipe(child)
    case Terminated(child) => println(s"${child.path.name} terminated...")
    case x: SendToLocal => local ! x
}
```

It seems to be working now.